# In VScode how can I stop the content of some functions being undefined when splitting .js files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

As soon as I split my javascript file into 2 separate files VScode intellisense tells me all the variables and functions relating to the first file are undefined in the second file, BUT the script runs fine in the browser!

The file logic.js is a big function that is called in main.js.

If I don't have logic.js in a giant function it works, but it needs to be in a function.

If I just copy and paste the contents of logic.js onto the end of main.js it's fine... I don't understand what is going on in VScode.

I call the scripts in the body (I have tried the head with the same results)

```
<body onload="mainLoop()">
<canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="650">Sorry, your browser can't display canvas!</canvas>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

I can call the files in the opposite order and the same thing happens, the program runs fine but VSCode stops intellisense working inside the huge function that is logic.js.

UPDATE here are the 2 files:

// FILE 1 main.js

```
"use strict";

// Set variables

/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let rightPressed = false;
let leftPressed = false;

var heroRotation = 0;
var bulletFired = false;
var numberOfZombies = 20;


/**
 * @description general purpose renderer
 * @param {*} state - the name of the object to act on
 */

function render2(state) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(state.xPosition, state.yPosition);
    ctx.rotate(state.angle * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.fillStyle = state.color;
    ctx.fillRect(state.width / -2, state.height / -2, state.width, state.height);
    ctx.restore();
}


/**
 * @description fire the heros gun
 * @param {*} state 
 */

function fire(state) {
    let fireangle = hero.angle;
    // while (state.xPosition > 50 && state.xPosition < (canvas.width - 50) || state.yPosition > 50 && state.yPosition < (canvas.height - 50)) {
    state.xPosition += 1 * Math.sin(fireangle);
    state.yPosition -= 1 * Math.cos(fireangle);
    // }
}


/**
 * @description Render the zombie objects
 */

function renderZombies() {
    for (let i = 0; i < allmyzombies.length; i++) {
        render2(allmyzombies[i]);
    }
}


/**
 * @description clear the canvas
 */

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// Factory functions

const createZombie = ({
    status = 1,
    width = 10,
    height = 10,
    xPosition,
    yPosition,
    angle = 0,
    color = "green"
}) => ({
    status,
    width,
    height,
    xPosition,
    yPosition,
    angle,
    color
});

const createHero = ({
    status = 1,
    width = 25,
    height = 50,
    xPosition,
    yPosition,
    angle = 0,
    color = "red"
}) => ({
    status,
    width,
    height,
    xPosition,
    yPosition,
    angle,
    color
});

const createBullet = ({
    status = 1,
    width = 5,
    height = 10,
    xPosition,
    yPosition,
    angle = 0,
    color = "white"
}) => ({
    status,
    width,
    height,
    xPosition,
    yPosition,
    angle,
    color
});


// Create the zombie objects using the factory function
var allmyzombies = [];

function createZombies(numberOfZombies) {

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfZombies; i++) {

        let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);

        if (x > (canvas.width / 2)) {
            x += (canvas.width / 3);
        } else {
            x -= (canvas.width / 3);
        }

        let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

        if (y > (canvas.height / 2)) {
            y += (canvas.width / 3);
        } else {
            y -= (canvas.height / 3);
        }

        allmyzombies[i] = createZombie({
            xPosition: x,
            yPosition: y
        });
    }
}

createZombies(numberOfZombies);

// create the hero using the factory function

const hero = createHero({
    xPosition: canvas.width / 2,
    yPosition: canvas.height / 2
});


// create the bullet using the factory function
// HOW TO USE BULLET WIDTH TO GET IN THE MIDDLE BEFORE ITS MADE?!

const bullet = createBullet({
    xPosition: (canvas.width + hero.width) / 2,
    yPosition: (canvas.height + hero.height) / 2
});


// Add event listener for keyboard handler

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

/**
 * @description keyDownHandler
 * @param {*} event - the event from the eventListener
 */

function keyDownHandler(event) {

    switch (event.code) {
        case "KeyF":
            bulletFired = true;
            break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
            leftPressed = true;
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            rightPressed = true;
            break;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}


/**
 * @description keyUpHandler
 * @param {*} event - the event from the eventListener
 */

function keyUpHandler(event) {
    switch (event.code) {
        case "ArrowLeft":
            leftPressed = false;
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            rightPressed = false;
            break;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}

function mainLoop() {
    clearCanvas();
    renderZombies();
    render2(hero);
    render2(bullet);
    logic();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // keeps running draw 60fps on paint
}


mainLoop(); // Call main loop function
```

// FILE 2 Logic.js

```
/**
 * @description game logic
 */

function logic() {
    for (let zombie of allmyzombies) {

        function moveZombieUp() {
            zombie.yPosition -= ZombieSpeed;
        }

        function moveZombieDown() {
            zombie.yPosition += ZombieSpeed;
        }

        function moveZombieLeft() {
            zombie.xPosition -= ZombieSpeed;
        }

        function moveZombieRight() {
            zombie.xPosition += ZombieSpeed;
        }

        let zombieStupidity = Math.random();
        let zombieStupidityThreshold = 0.75;

        if (zombieStupidity > zombieStupidityThreshold) {
            var zombieIsStupid = true;
        } else {
            var zombieIsStupid = false;
        }

        let ZombieSpeed = (Math.random() * 0.5);
        let zombieIsRightOfHero = zombie.xPosition > hero.xPosition;
        let zombieIsLeftOfHero = zombie.xPosition < hero.xPosition;
        let zombieIsBelowHero = zombie.yPosition > hero.yPosition;
        let zombieIsAboveHero = zombie.yPosition < hero.yPosition;

        if (zombieIsRightOfHero) {
            if (zombieIsStupid) {
                moveZombieRight();
            } else {
                moveZombieLeft();
            }
        }
        if (zombieIsLeftOfHero) {
            if (zombieIsStupid) {
                moveZombieLeft();
            } else
                moveZombieRight();
        }
        if (zombieIsBelowHero) {
            if (zombieIsStupid) {
                moveZombieDown();
            } else
                moveZombieUp();
        }
        if (zombieIsAboveHero) {
            if (zombieIsStupid) {
                moveZombieUp();
            } else
                moveZombieDown();
        }
        // detect zombie hero collision
        if (zombie.xPosition < hero.xPosition + hero.width &&
            zombie.xPosition + zombie.width > hero.xPosition &&
            zombie.yPosition < hero.yPosition + hero.height &&
            zombie.height + zombie.yPosition > hero.yPosition) {
            throw new Error("You died!");
        }
        // detect zombie bullet collision
        if (zombie.xPosition < bullet.xPosition + bullet.width &&
            zombie.xPosition + zombie.width > bullet.xPosition &&
            zombie.yPosition < bullet.yPosition + bullet.height &&
            zombie.height + zombie.yPosition > bullet.yPosition) {
            throw new Error("You killed a zombie!");
        }
    }

    if (bulletFired) {
        fire(bullet);
    }

    if (bullet.yPosition < 50 || bullet.yPosition > (canvas.height - 50)) {
        bulletFired = false;
    }

    // act on keypress controller info to rotate hero
    if (rightPressed) {
        hero.angle += 1;
    } else if (leftPressed) {
        hero.angle -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to post your code? And I can tell you, that it isn't about VSCode.

Comment: I think it needs to be opened in VSCode with the whole folder structure to find what is going on, it does not make sense to post all the text this time. Can you download it OK?

Comment: Trust me, we can handle, if you just post your two files inline in here!

Comment: OK, I uploaded the files :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't related to VS code.

The first file to load on the html can be recognized by the files after
In your case `logic.js` functions and vars are available to `main.js`

So you need to order them correctly and make sure there is no bidirectional dependencies. Such as main.js calling logic.js functions and logic.js calls main.js functions.

You need to order the js files in the html in the dependency order.
It would be easier to give a specific example if you'd post your code

Hint:
From the line

> If I just copy and paste the contents of logic.js onto the end of main.js it's fine...

I understand that logic.js functions use main.js data.
If so, you need to reorder the js loading in the html. 
```

```

Comment: I uploaded the files, please check my question again. Thanks!

Comment: From a brief look at the code from my mobile, it seems that logic.js should come After main.js in the html

Comment: I swapped the order as you suggested now it says logic is not defined in the console. This is strange as it seemed to work before when I swapped the order?! So how come it is not defined when it is loaded right after main.js? How can I call the function logic() in the file logic.js from main.js?

Comment: Of course it say that. As I wrote on the answer, bidirectional dependencies ate t optional. You cant call mani.js full cation from logid and logic.js function from main.js. You need to reorder the functions so one file will be depended on the other. And the other one isn't dependent

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go and come back to mark correct when I get it working.

Comment: Cheers, you were right. I have now discovered the [Revealing Module Pattern ] (https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/#revealing-module-pattern) and now my scope problems are solved :)